"Cannot read file" on ClaimCenter startup - webapp folder not generated on server startup on Ubuntu
Here is an error itself:
java.io.IOException: Cannot read file: /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/build/idea/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.addUniqueXmlFile(StartArgs.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.resolveExtraXmls(StartArgs.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
    at com.guidewire.commons.jetty.GWServerJettyServerMain.main(GWServerJettyServerMain.java:62)

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:42549', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 247

vm options:
-server
-ea
-Xdebug
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dgw.port=8080
-Dgw.cc.env=LOCAL
-Dgw.cc.serverid=LOCAL_SERVER
-Xms4G
-Xmx8G
-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar
-Dgw.server.mode=dev
-Dgwdebug=true
-Dgw.classpath.jar=true
-Dgw.plugins.gclasses.dir=idea-gclasses
-DgosuInit.supportDiscretePackages=true
-Dgw.webapp.dir=idea/webapp

Java home is /home/max/Java/dcevm-11.0.15+1 It also set as SDK in project structure and server config am running.
Am running Ubuntu 24.
After pressing Build -> Rebuild project in IDEA all the folders in /build appearing, except /webapp. Same behaviour on a local server startup.
As a workaround i copyed /webapp from a colleague (whos running a mac os), and manually put it to /idea folder, and it worked (ClaimCenter UI started ok). But after any clean it will require to copy again.
I found same question, but it does not have a solution.
Executed gwb clean -> gwb cleanidea -> gwb idea, and it works just fine. Here is a log of gwb webResources with error.
2024-09-11T16:39:28.663+0300 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :modules:configuration:compileJavascript UP-TO-DATE
2024-09-11T16:39:28.663+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :modules:configuration:compileJavascript' started
//some omited logs
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan] Node :modules:configuration:compileJavascript finished executing
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan] Node :modules:configuration:compileJavascript completed, executed: true
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.Node] Checking if all dependencies are complete for :modules:configuration:webResources
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.plan.Node] Dependency :modules:configuration:compileSass for :modules:configuration:webResources not yet completed
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on :modules:configuration
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.11 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1.11
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: acquired lock on :modules:configuration
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.11 started (1 worker(s) in use).
2024-09-11T16:39:28.711+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: acquired lock on root.1.11
2024-09-11T16:39:28.712+0300 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] :modules:configuration:compileSass (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
2024-09-11T16:39:29.884+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection] Discarding EOFException: java.io.EOFException
2024-09-11T16:39:29.884+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=6feab4c8-2b37-455c-954b-4f172901832e, currentDir=/home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
2024-09-11T16:39:29.891+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Daemon pid: 2009060
  log file: /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/gradle/cache/daemon/6.0.1/daemon-2009060.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-2009060.out.log -----
2024-09-11T16:39:28.735+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'' started
2024-09-11T16:39:28.735+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep] Implementation for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass': com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask_Decorated@814563e887b3aaa15d74e991dfc0cdae
2024-09-11T16:39:28.735+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep] Additional implementations for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass': [com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask_Decorated@814563e887b3aaa15d74e991dfc0cdae]
2024-09-11T16:39:28.735+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskSnapshotter] Snapshotting property cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0 (Output) for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'
2024-09-11T16:39:28.748+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass''
2024-09-11T16:39:28.748+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'' completed
2024-09-11T16:39:28.748+0300 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep] Caching disabled for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
2024-09-11T16:39:28.748+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Snapshot task inputs for :modules:configuration:compileSass'
2024-09-11T16:39:28.748+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Snapshot task inputs for :modules:configuration:compileSass' completed
2024-09-11T16:39:28.749+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Determining if task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' is up-to-date
2024-09-11T16:39:28.749+0300 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen has been removed.
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen/gw-theme--base.css has been removed.
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen/gw-theme--darcula.css has been removed.
2024-09-11T16:39:28.750+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep] Ensuring directory exists for property cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0 at /home/m.kozlyuk/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen
2024-09-11T16:39:28.751+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'.
2024-09-11T16:39:28.752+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute runTaskAction for :modules:configuration:compileSass' started
2024-09-11T16:39:28.752+0300 [LIFECYCLE] [com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask] START: Compiling SASS files...
2024-09-11T16:39:28.752+0300 [LIFECYCLE] [com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask] SASS: Compiling Pre Theme...
----- End of the daemon log -----

2024-09-11T16:39:29.892+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@610efda8
2024-09-11T16:39:29.892+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 29: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
2024-09-11T16:39:29.894+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.894+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2024-09-11T16:39:29.894+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:242)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:218)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:180)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:55)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:38)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:56)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:404)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:376)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:38)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:23)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:369)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-09-11T16:39:29.895+0300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> Task :modules:configuration:compileSass
Build operation 'Task :modules:configuration:compileSass' started
Putting task artifact state for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' into context took 0.0 secs.
Build operation 'Snapshot task inputs for :modules:configuration:compileSass' started
Theme File Names to Display Key Names found on Client Properties json:{"gw-theme--base":"Web.Theme.Base","gw-theme--darcula":"Web.Theme.Dark","gw-theme--green-white-web":"Web.Theme.Default","gw-theme--green-white-web-high-contrast":"Web.Theme.GreenWhiteWebHighContrast"}
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/themes.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/themes/partials.
Found 7 partial files.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/icon_font_maps.
Found 3 font icon files. These will be compiled per theme, outside of the theme wrapper class.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/environment/not_themed.
Found 6 environment files.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/modifier_functions.
Found 1 modifier function files. These will be compiled per theme before global and utility files but after theme file variables.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/themes/global_variables.
Found 65 global variable files. These will be compiled per theme, outside of the theme wrapper class.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/mixins_and_functions.
Found 7 utility files. These will be compiled per theme, outside of the theme wrapper class.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/environment/themed.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/components.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/platform/pages.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/apps.
Loading scss files from /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/sass/customer.
Found 127 sass files to be compiled inside the theme class wrapper for theme.
Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'' started
Implementation for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass': com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask_Decorated@814563e887b3aaa15d74e991dfc0cdae
Additional implementations for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass': [com.guidewire.pl.web.gradle.tasks.CompileSassTask_Decorated@814563e887b3aaa15d74e991dfc0cdae]
Snapshotting property cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0 (Output) for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'
Completing Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass''
Build operation 'Snapshot inputs and outputs before executing task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'' completed
Caching disabled for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Completing Build operation 'Snapshot task inputs for :modules:configuration:compileSass'
Build operation 'Snapshot task inputs for :modules:configuration:compileSass' completed
Determining if task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' is up-to-date
Task ':modules:configuration:compileSass' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen has been removed.
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen/gw-theme--base.css has been removed.
  Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0' file /Users/colleague/Documents/Code/JVM/guidewire/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen/gw-theme--darcula.css has been removed.
Ensuring directory exists for property cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0 at /home/max/IdeaProjects/GW/Guidewire10/ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/deploy/resources/css/gen
Executing actions for task ':modules:configuration:compileSass'.
Build operation 'Execute runTaskAction for :modules:configuration:compileSass' started
START: Compiling SASS files...
SASS: Compiling Pre Theme...


This probably won't help, but it's worth validating.  Can you run ".\gwb webResources" and try again?  Also note that Linux is not listed as a valid development workstation environment in the Platform Support Matrix published on community.guidewire.com (requires login).  That means this environment hasn't been tested by Guidewire for compatibility.

@MartinAavik I updated question, attached log of gwb webResources with error. The "Output property 'cssOutputDirectories.CSS_OUT_0'" lines contains some paths, of my colleague 's project. Initially i copyed whole project from him. May be this is somehow related with /webapp compilation?

It looks like your copying from your colleagues content has pulled in their context in a way that breaks at least the CSS build.  You need the webResources task to complete successfully to get a clean build.  I don't know what needs to be fixed to fix this, sadly.  I'd suggest clearing the build directory (at least) and retry your clean/cleanIdea.  Also "git clean -xdf" is a useful cleanup to try.  Good luck!

Does "gwb compile" work for you? If so, you could try this:

Execute gwb compile from the command line
Copy the folder /modules/configuration/deploy into /modules/configuration/build/idea
Rename the newly copied folder from deploy to webapp

It's similar to what you did but I think you could run it on your own machine and not depend on your colleague sending a copy of their webapps folder.
But as you said, running a gwb clean would delete the content of the idea folder and you would need to repeat the process. It is a good practice to clean the project from time to time, but it isn't necessary that often so this would just be a minor inconvenience in my opinion.

Rebuild and Refresh Project Dependencies & Check File Permissions
./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies

